# Print Manager in Ubuntu 14.04 automatically adds all network printers to print view

Tags: printing, system-settings

After upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 the print manager automatically added all network printers to my print view. Under 12.04  only those network printers where shown which I actually added manually.

this is kind of annoying because now I have to scroll myself through a huge list of printers in order to choose the one I need.

How can I disable this feature and force Ubuntu to show only the printers that I added manually?

Comment: did you get an answer?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this ?